# PowerBI - Pivot Rows on Matrix Visualization - Month + 1

Tags: matrix, powerbi, pivot

- I have a dataset in the following format. Notice InitialDate of July
  2022 has 1 corresponding row of RollingDate and Churn, June 2022 has
  2 corresponding rows, May has 3 etc etc

[image]

- Which I'm looking to display the results in a table matrix like this.

[image]

- The issue I'm finding it is that if I just use RollingDate as the
  Columns and Churn as the Values, it looks like this

[image]

- But what I want is this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add a Rank column to the table as follows:

```
Rank = 
VAR __InitialDate = 'Table'[InitialDate]
RETURN
RANKX(
    FILTER( Table , Table[InitialDate]  = __InitialDate ),
    Table[RollingDate],
    ,ASC
)-1
```

[image]